# How to make python packages callable from text editor like sublime3, visual studio code?

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to `import gtts` module in python. I have successfully installed `gtts` using `pip install gtts`. I can see four folders namely `gtts`, `gtts_token`, `gTTS-2.0.3.dist-info`, `gTTS_token-1.1.3.dist-info` in 
`C:\Users\Nishant\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`. I have already add the path of this folder to my environment variable `path`. Now, when in the interactive shell I write `from gtts import gTTS` it shows `error: no such file or directory.`

I have googled for the solution and everywhere I was asked to add path of the directory to my environment variable, which I have tried earlier.

Comment: Did you named any of your folder name in your project as gtts ?

Comment: no @ozcanyarimdunya